# Help with declaring and using dynamically allocated Array in C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I need to declare an array of arrays and so using the code below to accomplish that:

```
int **  maxc = new int *[proc_num];//memory allocated for elements of rows
      for (int i = 0; i < proc_num; i++)
      {
            maxc[i] = new int[n];//memory allocated for  elements of each column.
      }
```

The problem is, the code above does not seem to compile. I get the following compilation error:

```
A value of type "int *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int"
```

---

Here's the full code:

```
//#include<math.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
/*
Banker's algorithm Implementation
*/
 int main(void)
 {
      int n=0;//number of resources we will  be dealing with 
      int proc_num =0;//Total number of processes to share available resources
      int* a = NULL;  // pointer to an int with initial set to point to nothing
     // int* maxc = NULL;
      int* maxR=NULL;
      int* avail = NULL;
      int* avail_temp = NULL;
      //int** alloc = NULL;
      int* unalloc = NULL;

      std::cout<<endl;
      std::cout <<" What is number of resources to be shared? :";
      cin >> n;
      std::cout<<endl;
      while(std::cin.fail())
      {
            std::cout<< " Error Please provide valid number !" <<endl;
            std::cin.clear() ;
            std::cout<<endl;
            std::cout <<" What is number of resources to be shared? :";
            cin >> n;
            std::cout<<endl;
      }

      maxR = new int[n];  // Allocate n ints and save ptr in maxc -- holds the max resources available.
      //get the maximum number of each Resources/ Ie Total Resources Available
      for(int i =0; i < n; i++)
      {
            int maxcin=0;
            std::cout << i;
            std::cout<< ". How many of resource #";
            std::cout<< i;
            std::cout<< " do you need to share ?"; 
            cin>>maxcin;
            maxR[i] = maxcin;
      }
      //<8,7,5,9>");

      std::cout<<endl;
      std::cout << "How many processes to share available resources?";
      cin>>proc_num;
      std::cout<<endl;

      int **  maxc = new int *[proc_num];//memory allocated for elements of rows
      for (int i = 0; i < proc_num; i++)
      {
            maxc[i] = new int*[n];//memory allocated for  elements of each column.
      }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason not to use any of the safer/more comfortable, idiomatic ways that C++ offers to achieve the same functionality as plain, multidimensional arrays?

Comment: If you are attempting to write a multi-language source file I suggest you do not use `new`, or `::`, or `<<` (except as bitwise shift operator), or `namespace`, ..

Comment: Can you show a complete example please?  The code here has no errors, and compiles perfectly fine on my own copy of VC10(assuming proc_num and n are properly declared).

Comment: I am taking it from this example here  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/arrayDinamic.aspx

Comment: Reason I am using this is because this is just a quick project, I can make changes later but I need a quick solution and Arrays is what I know to use at this time.

Comment: That's nice.  But I still need to see your complete code, main function, includes and everything.

Comment: Yes, the complete code is needed, the error is almost certainly not caused by any of the code you posted, see unapersson's answer below. It compiles just fine when wrapped in a main.

Comment: @Kobojunkie - Benjamin is right - the snippet here looks correct in itself so, to find the error, we need to see what in the context is breaking it. For example, is there a scope/name resolution issue, so that another definition of "maxc" might be used in preference to the one you expect? From the indentation mismatch, it looks like the declaration of maxc and the loop are cut/pasted from different parts of your code, so the appearance here that the maxc hides any other definitions with the same name may not apply to your real code.

Comment: BTW - in my view, sharing non-trivial data structures between C and C++ is a bad idea. Sharing information is OK, but keep the data structure code in one language or the other (preferably using C++ standard library containers), and provide access functions for use in C.

Comment: @Steve314: Regarding the indentation mismatch.  That probably comes from selecting starting at the first word of the first line instead of the beginning of the line, so the indent is copied on all lines but the first.

Comment: I added the whole code as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have problems with getting the declarations correct, but your real problem is not using standard containers to do the work for you.

This code:

```
  int **  maxc = new int *[proc_num];//memory allocated for elements of rows
  for (int i = 0; i < proc_num; i++)
  {
        maxc[i] = new int*[n];//memory allocated for  elements of each column.
  }
```

Can be corrected to this to make it compile.

```
  int **  maxc = new int *[proc_num];
  for (int i = 0; i < proc_num; i++)
  {
        maxc[i] = new int[n];
             //     ^^^^ Note no star here.
  }
```

But it is still not good code as you are not taking into account exceptions (this code will leak if any allocation fails). During use if your code generates an exception you are going to leak all the memory.

A better solution would be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >  maxc(proc_num, std::vector<int>(n, 0)); // even initializes all elements to 0
```

If you want to get fancy you look up the [boost multi-dimensional array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) this may give you some small performance improvements (if you are doing matrix multiplication etc).

if you really want to do it by hand then I would start learning about classes and RAII.

Answer (score 2):

What the error now you get is entirely different from what you posted earlier. In the final for loop -

```
maxc[i] = new int*[n];
```

should be -

```
maxc[i] = new int[n];
```

In the snippet you earlier posted, it was correct. Also, you should deallocate resources acquired by `new[]` using `delete[]`, else memory leak prevails.

Comment: @Kobojunkie - As every one suggested, post the entire code in your question then. There is nothing wrong in what you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're encountering is in this section of the code you posted:

```
int **  maxc = new int *[proc_num];
for (int i = 0; i < proc_num; i++)
{
    maxc[i] = new int*[n];
}
```

Inside the for-loop, you're allocating a new array of `int` pointers, but the original type for `maxc` was of type pointer-to-pointer.  In this context that could also be construed to say `maxc` is a pointer that points to an array of pointers.  That of course accomplished on the first assignment, where you return a pointer from `new` that is pointing to an array of `int*`.  Therefore the statement inside the for-loop is assigning the wrong type to each array element.  The type for the array elements `maxc[x]` are `int` pointers, which means that they must point to either one or more objects of type `int`, not elements of type `int*`.  But your `new` operator in the loop is trying to allocate another array of `int` pointers, and return a pointer to that allocated array, meaning the type returned is `int**` again, and that's not correct. So you should change the inside of your loop to read:

```
maxc[i] = new int[n]; //allocate an array of int's, and return an int pointer
```

I noticed the first segment of code you posted actually does this, so maybe you're encountering a simple typo you missed?

Finally, when you delete this memory, since each row was created using `new`, you will have to call `delete` on each row representing the array of `int`'s.  Next, you will have to call delete on the column representing the array of `int` pointers that were pointing to the array of `int`'s.  So freeing all the memory allocated would look like the following:

```
for (int i=0; i < proc_num; i++)
{
    //call delete on each pointer in each column of the array that is pointing to a
    //row array of int's
    delete [] maxc[i];  
}

//call delete on the pointer pointing to the column of 
//the array that contains the original int pointers that were
//pointing to each of the row arrays of int's
delete [] maxc;
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
int main() {
    int proc_num = 100;
    int n = 42;
    int **  maxc = new int *[proc_num];//memory allocated for elements of rows
    for (int i = 0; i < proc_num; i++) {
            maxc[i] = new int[n];//memory allocated for  elements of each column.
    }
}
```

compiles just fine for me.

Comment: int proc_num = 0;
    int n = 0;
//User provides values for proc_num and n during runtime 

    int **  maxc = new int *[proc_num];//memory allocated for elements of rows
    for (int i = 0; i < proc_num; i++) 
   {
            maxc[i] = new int[n];//memory allocated for  elements of each column.
    }